# The password_hash doesn´t work no matter where i put it in the code i can´t figure it out?

Tags: php, hash, password-hash

I´m trying to get this form right but i can´t seem to find out whats wrong.
No matter where i put the hash in the code i can´t seem to get it to work.
I tried to get the input out from the form to convert it to a hash with password_hash(@psw, PASSWORD_DEFAULT) but no matter where i put it it won´t work.... do i need to say i am a newbie at this =)

````
if(isset($_POST["uname"]) && isset($_POST["psw"]))
{
    // check if user exist.
    $file=fopen("log.txt","r");
    $finduser = false;
    while(!feof($file))
    {
        $line = fgets($file);
        $array = explode(";",$line);
        if(trim($array[0]) == $_POST['uname'])
        {
            $finduser=true;
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose($file);
 
    // register user
    if( $finduser )
    {
        echo $_POST["uname"];
        echo ' fanns redan registrerad!';
    }
    else
    {
        $file = fopen("log.txt", "a");
        //funkar ej
        $psw = password_hash($_POST['psw'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);//funkar ej
        fputs($file,$_POST["uname"].";".$_POST["psw"]."\r\n");
        fclose($file);
        echo $_POST["uname"];
        echo " är nu registrerad!";
    }
}

 
if(isset($_POST['login']))   // it checks whether the user clicked login button or not 
{
     $uname = $_POST['uname'];
     $psw = $_POST['psw'];
 
    if(isset($_POST["uname"]) && isset($_POST["psw"])){
    $file = fopen('log.txt', 'r');
    $good=false;
    while(!feof($file)){
        $line = fgets($file);
        $array = explode(";",$line);
    if(trim($array[0]) == $_POST['uname'] && trim($array[1]) == $_POST['psw']){
            $good=true;
            header("Location:index.php"); 
            break;
        }else{
        echo "Ogiltigt användarnamn eller lösenord";
    }
    
    }
  fclose($file);
}
}

?>

<html>
<head>
<title> Registreringssida </title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
    <table width="200" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>Användarnamn:</td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="uname" > </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lösenord:</td>
    <td><input type="password" name="psw"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <input type="submit" name="reg" value="Ny Användare"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
<form action="" method="post">
    <table width="200" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>Användarnamn:</td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="uname" > </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lösenord:</td>
    <td><input type="password" name="psw"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <input type="submit" name="login" value="Logga In"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: Duplicate of [Why does the hash function not work no matter where i put it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66515205/why-does-the-hash-function-not-work-no-matter-where-i-put-it)

Comment: You mean the hashed password is not being written into the text file? Well, that’s because you’re writing the “unhashed” password into the file!

Comment: @Professorval haha thanks i figured this much but i don´t know how to solve it..i have tried multiple ways but none seem to work... i hope someone could help explain to me where i go wrong..

  `{
        $file = fopen("log.txt", "a");
        //funkar ej
        $psw = password_hash($_POST['psw'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);//funkar ej
        fputs($file,$_POST["uname"].";".$_POST["psw"]."\r\n");
        fclose($file);
        echo $_POST["uname"];
        echo " är nu registrerad!";
    }
}`
As i see it i am converting the input psw to a hashed one w the same variable name of psw